# Unable to pass variable in query

Tags: json, python-2.7, https, python-requests, parameter-passing

I am new in python. I am trying to pass variable "ord" value in below query parameter,

ord = '12345'

query = { '$filter': 'OrderNo in ord' }

response = requests.get('https://example.com/orrderDetails', param=query)

print(response.json())

"get" request is successful if "ord" value is hardcoded but how to use variable as "ord" value will change (taking as argument) on each request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this trick

```
var = 'OrderNo in %s' % ord
query = { '$filter': var }
```

I hope it works.